# Deep learning vs attractor networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Hopfield showed remarkable properties in a simple, fully interconnected network. He called these properties "emergent intelligence" (1982 PNAS).

It's been over 35 years. Why haven't (generalized) Hopfield nets become more popular? Is there some fundamental difficulty getting them to work (eg local minima) or are deep learning nets just more useful?

Thank you.